# Write a program which places user's input in a float array until user inserts 0

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops, pointers

Currently I'm working on an academic assignment, which seems to be very simple and basic, but unfortunately I have no idea why I receive this strange output.

The idea is this: User is asked to enter some float numbers which are saved into the float array called `T[N]`. Now, when user hits `0` and enter, `while()` loop stops, and program should count both sum and average of inserted already numbers, however because I've used *size* control variable, it performs it only to the last entered element, whose index is equal `size - 1`, due to indexing thingy. For I/O control purposes I want to check if entered numbers are the same to the ones which appears on the screen with `printf()`, however I'm getting only `2` arguments out of inserted `N` (it's always `2nd` and `4th`), of course `sum` & `avg` gets distorted pretty bad afterwards. Any ideas what's that about?

Here is a basic code:

```
int sum(const float * tab, unsigned int size, float *result) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        *result += *tab;
    }
    return 1;
}

int avg(const float* tab, unsigned int size, float *result) {
    sum(tab, size, result);
    *result = *result / size - 1;
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    unsigned int size = 1, i;
    float T[N], val = 0, wynik;
    float *result = &wynik, *tab = T;
    while (scanf("%f", &val) == 1 && val != 0) {
        if (scanf("%f", &val) == 0) {
            printf("Wprowadzono niepoprawny znak. Koczenie...\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else if (val == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            *tab = val;
            tab++;
            size++;
        }
    }
    tab = T;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        printf("%.2lf ", *tab);
        tab++;
    }
    tab = T;
    sum(tab, size, result);
    printf("\nSuma elementow tablicy T[%u]: %lf\n", size - 1, *result);
    avg(tab, size, result);
    printf("Srednia elementow tablicy T[%u]: %f\n", size - 1, *result);
    /*if (scanf("%f", &val) == 0) {
        printf("Wprowadzono niepoprawny znak. Konczenie...\n)";
    }
    else if (val == 0) {
        break;
    }*/
    getch();
    return 1;
}
```

And that's what actually happens when program reads 0 from user's input:

[image]

**edit.** Don't mind this %.lf and %.f data types, I've just didn't replace it, end result is the same anyway.

Comment: "static float array" ??? you array is not static... just say "float array", damm your code is very ugly.

Comment: by static I mean:
#define N 100
...
float T[N];
you get it right now?

Comment: "N is defined as 100 at the beginning". Don't say it in the narrative, post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as ***text*** in the question.

Comment: @TheInvisibleMan: That is an okay use of the English word “static,” but `static` has a specific meaning in C, so you should avoid using “static” with its general English meaning when discussing C unless you ensure the context is clear.

Comment: ok, then I'll use "predefined" or "preset" from now on if it'll please you.

Comment: You have `float wynik` and `float *result = &wynik` and you pass this pointer around but you don't initialise `wynik` or `*result` or in the functions it is passed to. Undefined behaviour. Please use a debugger.

Comment: I suggest you break the assignment into parts and do one part at a time. First, write a program that reads the numbers and stops when zero is input. Just print each number as it is read. When that is working, modify the program to record all the numbers in an array, then print them at the end. When that is working, modify the program to add the numbers and print the sum. When that is working, modify the program to calculate the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix problem myself, because none of you referred to a core issue.

1) I've changed part:

```
while (scanf("%f", &val) == 1 && val != 0) {
if (scanf("%f", &val) == 0) {
    printf("Wprowadzono niepoprawny znak. Koczenie...\n");
    return 0;
}
else if (val == 0) {
    break;
}
else {
    *tab = val;
    tab++;
    size++;
}
```

}

to:

```
    while (scanf("%f", &val) == 1 && val != 0) {
    *tab = val;
    tab++;
    size++;
    fflush(stdin);
}
```

2) I've added to *int sum()* only this part `tab++;`, so it looks like this now:

```
int sum(const float * tab, unsigned int size, float *result) {
unsigned int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    *result += *tab;
    tab++;
}
return 1;
```

}

3) Inside *int avg()* I've left only this:

```
*result = *result / size;
```

Anyway, thanks for reply.

Evidences:

#1

[image]

#2

[image]

#3.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
int sum(const float * tab, unsigned int size, float *result) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        *result += *tab;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This adds `*tab` to `*result` `size` times. It never changes where `tab` points, so it adds the same thing repeatedly.

Additionally, it does not assign an initial value to `*result`. The parameter `result` is passed from `avg`, which receives it from `main`, where it points to `wynik`, but `wynik` is also never assigned an initial value. Thus, this code would be adding `*tab` to something whose initial value is unknown. Hence the final result is unknown.

```
int avg(const float* tab, unsigned int size, float *result) {
    sum(tab, size, result);
    *result = *result / size - 1;
    return 1;
}
```

After calling `sum`, this divides `*result` by `size` and then subtracts one. That does not calculate an average. Perhaps you intended to divide by `size - 1`. That would calculate the average if there were `size - 1` things.

```
int main() {
    unsigned int size = 1, i;
    float T[N], val = 0, wynik;
```

`wynik` is never assigned a value.

```
    float *result = &wynik, *tab = T;
    while (scanf("%f", &val) == 1 && val != 0) {
        if (scanf("%f", &val) == 0) {
            printf("Wprowadzono niepoprawny znak. Koczenie...\n");
            return 0;
```

This scans for two numbers, one for the first `scanf` and one for the second. I suspect you only wanted to scan for one.

```
        }
        else if (val == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            *tab = val;
            tab++;
            size++;
        }
    }
    tab = T;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        printf("%.2lf ", *tab);
        tab++;
    }
    tab = T;
    sum(tab, size, result);
```

You have only read `size - 1` numbers (not including the zero that ended the input), but `sum` adds `size` times.

```
    printf("\nSuma elementow tablicy T[%u]: %lf\n", size - 1, *result);
    avg(tab, size, result);
```

`*result` was modified in `sum` (but never assigned an initial value) and is now modified again in `avg` (when it calls `sum` again) without being reset. Perhaps you want to set `*result` to zero when `sum` starts.

```
    printf("Srednia elementow tablicy T[%u]: %f\n", size - 1, *result);
    /*if (scanf("%f", &val) == 0) {
        printf("Wprowadzono niepoprawny znak. Konczenie...\n)";
    }
    else if (val == 0) {
        break;
```

I stopped tracking the control flow. You are testing `scanf` and `val` too many times. The solution is simpler than your program.

```
    }*/
    getch();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code a lot, you miss understand a lot of C concept for example:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    *result += *tab;
}
```

Here `tab` never change so `*tab` is always the same number, increment `i` do nothing. You should use `*result = tab[i]`.

```
unsigned int size = 1, i;
```

why do you start by 1 ? Just start by zero this will be more simple, why use `unsigned int` and not `size_t` ? why declare more that one variable by line this make the code hard to read ?

```
tab = T;
for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    printf("%.2lf ", *tab);
    tab++;
}
```

Again you could just use `i` with `tab[i]`. By the way, compare with zero to stop the program is not a good practice but you request it so...

Well, you need more training in C here a code exemple to help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 100

static bool sum(const float *numbers, size_t size, float *result) {
    *result = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        *result += numbers[i];
    }
    return false;
}

static bool avg(const float *numbers, size_t size, float *result) {
    if (size == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (sum(numbers, size, result)) {
        return true;
    }
    *result = *result / size;
    return false;
}

int main(void) {
    float numbers[N];
    size_t size = 0;
    while (size < N && scanf("%f", numbers + size) == 1 && numbers[size] != 0) {
        size++;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%.2f ", numbers[i]);
    }
    float result;
    sum(numbers, size, &result);
    printf("\nSuma elementow tablicy T[%zu]: %f\n", size, result);
    avg(numbers, size, &result);
    printf("Srednia elementow tablicy T[%zu]: %f\n", size, result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are over-complicate things.

The functions:

```
int sum(const float * tab, unsigned int size, float *result);
int avg(const float* tab, unsigned int size, float *result);
```

expect third parameter as pointer to float. Pass the pointer to `wynik`

```
sum(tab, size, &wynik);
avg(tab, size, &wynik);
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(const float * tab, unsigned int size, float *result) {
    unsigned int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        *result += *(tab+i);
    }
    return 1;
}

int avg(const float* tab, unsigned int size, float *result) {

    sum(tab, size, result);
    *result = *result / size - 1;
    return 1;
}

#define N 10

int main() {
    unsigned int size = 1, i;
    float T[N], val = 0, wynik=0;

    float *result = &wynik, *tab = T;

    while (scanf("%f", &val) == 1 && val != 0) {
        if (scanf("%f", &val) == 0) {
            printf("Wprowadzono niepoprawny znak. Koczenie...\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else if (val == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            *tab = val;
            tab++;
            size++;
        }
    }

    tab = T;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        printf("%.2lf ", *tab);
        tab++;
    }

    tab = T;
    sum(tab, size, &wynik);
    printf("\nSuma elementow tablicy T[%u]: %f\n", size - 1, wynik);

    avg(tab, size, &wynik);
    printf("Srednia elementow tablicy T[%u]: %f\n", size - 1, wynik);
    /*if (scanf("%f", &val) == 0) {
        printf("Wprowadzono niepoprawny znak. Konczenie...\n)";
    }
    else if (val == 0) {
        break;
    }*/
    getch();
    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1                                                                                                                                            
2                                                                                                                                            
3                                                                                                                                            
4                                                                                                                                            
5                                                                                                                                            
0                                                                                                                                            
2.00 4.00                                                                                                                                    
Suma elementow tablicy T[2]: 6.000000                                                                                                        
Srednia elementow tablicy T[2]: 3.000000
```

Comment: You left a call [OP's call] to `sum` inside `avg` so `sum` is called [needlessly] and the result is discarded

Comment: @CraigEstey Thank you for your comment. Yes, you are absolutely right! I did not debug the whole algorithm leaving it to the OP...